# jQuery Form Validation redirect if success validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have jQuery Login Form that the function is to check user validation.

Here is the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#button_sign_in').click(function(){
             console.log('login');
            $.ajax({
                url: "login",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log('data:'+data);
                    if (data.user) {
                        $('#lblUsername').text(data.user.username);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#username').focus();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error:'+e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The logic is, if wrong username or password then the button will shake. If correct login then redirect to the home page.

and here is my PHP function :

```
require ("functions/_db_.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM t_users WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'");
$found = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($found > 0)
{
    header('location:home.php');
}
```

Now the problem is : if login corrected, the page won't redirect to home page.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your PHP Script as bellow

```
        //Check your inputs against to mysql injections
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM t_users WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'");
        $found = mysql_num_rows($query);


        if ($found > 0)
        {
            $res='SUCCESS';
        }
        else
        {
            $res='ERROR';
        }

        $ary=array("status"=>$res);

        echo json_encode($ary); //Json output - we are sending the assynchronus data in json format
```

and Your Script

```
$.ajax
({
    url: "login",
    type: "post",
    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
    dataType:'json', //We need ajax data in json type
    success: function (data) 
    {
        if (data.status=='SUCCESS') //status is proper of the json object, which we gave in php code in above script
        {
            window.location='home.php'; 
        }
        else 
        {
            $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
            $('#username').focus();
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('error:'+e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you're not doing the redirect itself?

```
success: function (data) {
                    //console.log('data:'+data);
                    if (data.user) {
                        $('#lblUsername').text(data.user.username);
                        window.location = '/home.php'; // redirect to the homepage
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#username').focus();
                    }
                }
```

PHP redirect using header won't work if you send it to the client via AJAX. You have to redirect it on the client-side using JS in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.user) 
{
   $('#lblUsername').text(data.user.username);
   window.location = "home.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, i think you have the problem at PHP side, not the javascript. 
Considering this, here is your solution , not location it is Location

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

[Document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: First: please tell me are you getting value for $found?
Second: are you getting any warning or notices, if so, send me the msg

Comment: Thats why, maybe I missing something or must send value from $found to ajax success? There is no error there. You can see the demo in : http://bootply.com/tagged/modal, click login

Answer (score 0):

When you do AJAX call to a php script, calling `header()` will not load a new page in the browser. You can respond to AJAX call by `echo 'success/fail'` and redirect to the desired page yourself by checking the response in the `success:` part of AJAX. And don forget to set the php session, and check whether the user login made successful or not in the page which you want to display after login. So your code in php will be,

```
if ($found > 0) {
  //set session here
  echo 'success';
}
else
  echo 'fail';
```

and in Ajax,

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data == 'success') {
    window.location = "home_page.php";
  }
  else {
    $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
    $('#username').focus();
  }
}
```

in you hompage php,
check for the session.